# Add precompiled dynamic library to APK when using QBS build system

Tags: android, c++, qbs

I am trying to compile my SDL2 project for android using QBS. I built SDL2 as dynamic library using NDK's ndk-build tool. But can't figure out how to make QBS (which I use in my project) include libSDL2.so to the resulting APK.

I have tried approach with FileTagger, mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466967/copying-precompiled-libraries-to-build-directory-or-adding-them-to-path-in-a-qbs) question, but no luck:

```
FileTagger {
    patterns: ["deps/SDL2/libs/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.so"]
    fileTags: ["android.nativelibrary"]
}
```

Comment: We haven't implemented this yet, but it's on the radar.

Comment: @Jake, thanks for the response. I guess I'll just use static linking until it is implemented. Is there any bugreport\issue for this feature so I can track the progress?